# What are Function Pointers Ponting To?

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the following code and output:

```
#include <iostream>

int Add(int a, int b) {
  return a + b;
}

int Subtract(int a, int b) {
  return a - b;
}

int main() {
  int (*fn1)(int, int);
  int (*fn2)(int, int);
  fn1 = &Add;
  fn2 = &Subtract;

  std::cout << "fn1 = " << fn1 << "\n";
  std::cout << "*fn1 = " << *fn1 << "\n";
  std::cout << "fn2 = " << fn2 << "\n";
  std::cout << "*fn2 = " << *fn2 << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
fn1 = 1
*fn1 = 1
fn2 = 1
*fn2 = 1
```

As a pointer, I would expect `fn1` and `fn2` to be memory addresses, and I don't really know what to expect for `*fn1` and `*fn2`.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_pointer), "a function pointer points to executable code within memory", but I don't see how "executable code within memory" corresponds with "1".

Comment: You print a `bool` value here...: `true` (as non null pointer).

Comment: fn2 and *fn2 is the same. Also ********fn2 is the same :)

Comment: You are a pointer?!

Comment: Cast your pointers to `uintptr_t` before printing so std::cout interprets them as integers

Answer (score 3):

`*fn1` is a function lvalue, and such a value decays to a pointer to that function in most circumstances, including when passed as a function call argument.

You can dereference the result of the decay to get another function lvalue, ad infinitum: `*****fn1`, `***********fn1`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> What are Function Pointers Ponting To?

It depends on what kind of function pointer it is. For non-member function pointer (as in your example), the pointer usually points to the actual code for the function (though on some architectures, such as PowerPC, it may point into a special "function descriptor" instead):

To examine that value, you should print it as `void *`, and not as `bool` (which is what you have done in your example).

```
std::cout << "fn1 = " << (void*)fn1 << std::endl;
```

Another way to examine it is using a debugger. For example, in GDB:

```
(gdb) p/a fn1
(gdb) p/a fn2
```

Comment: Why is it printing as a `bool` in the first place?  And why does casting it to a `void` pointer elucidate the "true" value?